# D3 Invert Selection From Event Listener (this)

Tags: css, d3.js

I have a visual with many rects, and I have given them the class `graph_rects`. My goal is when the user clicks on a rect with that class, it will keep that rect the same color but turn all the other `graph_rects` gray. However my approach did not work and unfortunately it's hard to trouble shoot because there were no errors in the log.

My CSS rule for the graying out:

```
.graph_rects unselected {
    fill:gray;
}
```

My D3 event listener at rect creation/appending:

```
.on('click', function(d) {
    return d3.selectAll(".graph_rects:not(this)").classed('unselected',true)
})
```

I'm pretty sure my CSS is ok, my hunch is my d3 logic is not right.

**Update**

Here are some relevant lines of code that may help piece together why the proposed solutions is not working for me (yet). I am trying to troubleshoot whether or not my matrix of graphs (such as [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663) one) is the culprit by making the selector have redundant ids. So I created a id that has the `i` and `j` for the corresponding dimensions as well as `i` for the index. This way it should be impossible for a rect to have the same id with another rect from a different graph.

```
.attr('id', function(d,i) {
    return String(p.i+p.j)+i
})
```

Also here is my event listener as per the suggested solution:

```
.on('click', function(d) {
    d3.selectAll('.graph_rects:not(#'+this.id+')').classed('unselected',true)
    d3.select(this).classed('unselected',false)
})
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.graph_rects:not(#219)' is not a valid selector

What did I not do right I wonder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem, your CSS should be:

```
.graph_rects.unselected {
    fill: gray;
}
```

But that's not the big issue here. The big issue lies here:

```
d3.selectAll(".graph_rects:not(this)")
```

In that line, you're telling D3 to not select any `<this></this>` element. Of course, such elements don't exist!

There are several ways to achieve what you want, and different coders have their favourite approach (I have mine, which doesn't use the `not`). However, I'll try to provide a solution keeping that `not` selector: instead of using `not(this)`, which literally selects something called `this`, you can select by class or by id (remember, IDs must be unique). For example:

```
d3.selectAll(".graph_rects:not(#" + this.id + ")")
```

Here is an example, click the bars:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var rects = svg.selectAll("planck")
  .data(d3.range(10))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "graph_rects")
  .attr("id", function(d, i) {
    return "rect" + i
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 25
  })
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("height", 150)
  .attr("fill", "firebrick")
  .on('click', function() {
    d3.selectAll(".graph_rects:not(#" + this.id + ")").classed('unselected', true);
    d3.select(this).classed("unselected", false)
  })
```

```css
.graph_rects.unselected {
  fill: gray;
}

.graph_rects {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Great explanation! It makes sense intuitively to me now, but I still can't get it working on my particular document. I actually have several graphs in my document and I update my `data` var for each graph. I suppose this could actually result in ids that are not unique (as `(d,i)` would start over for each). I don't get an error though. Does it throw an error if there are redundant ids?

Comment: @ArashHowaida No, it doesn't, and that's why you have to pay attention to it. In your case, I suggest that you use another method, instead of defining a class as you're doing right now.

Comment: I have got an error, and have updated my post. Hope this info will be helpful. One other thing that just dawned on me is that I'm using D3 v3, but I don't believe the basics of selections changed that much, so maybe that won't be an issue.

Comment: @ArashHowaida Please, don't mix different problems in the same question, and don't edit your question to ask a new problem (write a new question instead). The issue here was already solved, as I showed in my answer. What you have here is a **new** problem: IDs cannot start by a number.

Comment: Hmm, that would explain a lot. It's hard to know you have a separate problem when you are in the midst of it all. It honestly seemed like one big issue. In all fairness, I guess you are right. Thanks for sticking with me.